# Redpin server is not reachable

Tags: java, indoor-positioning-system, redpin

I am running redpin.jar on my PC as:

```
java -jar redpin.jar 8000
```

I have RedpinAndroid-signed.apk and have installed it on my LG android phone. I have also configured server preferences in the android app with my PC WIFI IP and port i.e. 8000.

I still get the error: **Redpin server is not reachable.**

Kindly guide.

Comment: Does your PC have a firewall?  Can you telnet to port 8000 from another computer to your PC?  If you do a netstat -a does port 8000 show as "listening"?

Comment: My PC has no firewall. If I telnet from another computer to my computer i.e. telnet 172.16.17.66 8000 ..................I get the response: Could not open connection to the host on port 8000: connection failed.   It means that nothing is running on it 8000 as I had stopped the server while telnetting from another computer. netstat -na | find "8000" returns NULL or nothing :)

Comment: When I run the server, then netstat -na | find "8000" returns 2 entries: TCP    0.0.0.0:8000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:8000              [::]:0                 LISTENING                                               I have noticed, there is no IP just 0.0.0.0, isnt it strange ?

Comment: No, TCP 0.0.0.0 means that it's listening on all available IPs (if you box had more than one, you could optionally have only listen on certain interfaces.)  The second one is your IPv6 interface.  So with the server running, does telnet connect?

Comment: when the sever is running, "telnet localhost 8000" goes to a blank screen on command-line. wat does this mean ?

Comment: If it goes to a blank screen with just a blinking cursor that means something (presumably your server) is listening on that port and that it isn't blocked by the firewall.  So you can scratch that possible problem off your list.